# tor traffic routing within tor network

Tags: tor

I understand there is entry node, middle node and exit node when a user accesses an internet resource like https://www.google.com while coeected to the tor network.

Is the concept the same if the user, while within the tor network, visits a resource within the tor network like http://rfyb5tlhiqtiavwhikdlvb3fumxgqwtgxnaanxtiqibidqlox5nnspqd.onion/? Is there entry, middle and exit nodes involved as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exit node at all.

When visiting a *Hidden Service* or *onion* site, your Browser sets up a 3-hop connection to a *Rendezvous* node. The *onion* site also sets up a 3-hop connection to the *Rendezvous* node. The *Rendezvous* node relays everything through the effective 7-hop connection.

There is more detail on how that *Rendezvous* node is found and connection handshakes, but once set up that's the basics.